# Trouble with my NVIDIA Geforce 6150 on Debian Wheezy

Tags: debian, nvidia-geforce, debian-wheezy

I own a HP Pavilion dv2025nr which has a NVIDIA GeForce Go 6150 card. I installed Debian Wheezy which currently installs GNOME 3. I need to install nvidia-glx in order to use my card at full potential.

However, after installing the nvidia-glx, removing the xserver-xorg-video-nouveau package the X won't start. It keeps black, and if I manage to go to tty, I see several lines of "Kill proccess PID (name): Out of memory..."; that explains why the HDD led is constantly on.

According to http://www.nvidia.com/object/IO_32667.html my card is NOT a legacy card, so it should work.

My system is Debian Wheezy:

```
manu@pavla:~$ uname -a
Linux pavla 3.0.0-1-686-pae #1 SMP Sat Aug 27 16:41:03 UTC 2011 i686 GNU/Linux
```

Installed NVIDIA related packages:

```
manu@pavla:~$ aptitude search ~i~dnvidia
i A glx-alternative-nvidia        
i A libgl1-nvidia-alternatives
i A libgl1-nvidia-glx
i A libglx-nvidia-alternatives
i   libvdpau1
i   nvidia-alternative
i   nvidia-detect
i   nvidia-glx
i A nvidia-installer-cleanup
i A nvidia-kernel-common
i A nvidia-kernel-dkms
i A nvidia-support
i A nvidia-vdpau-driver
i A xserver-xorg-video-nvidia
```

Any ideas?

Best regards,
Manuel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question was also posted on Debian Forums http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=72370&p=40334.

The solution was to simply create a /etc/X11/xorg.conf with the following content:

```
Section "Module"
    Load        "glx"
EndSection

Section "Device"
   Identifier  "Video Card"
   Driver      "nvidia"
EndSection
```